# initialization in while loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm new to python and having problem understanding the code snippet below.
I don't understand why sum is initialized to 0, not 1. Can anyone explain this initialization?

```
n = 4
sum = 0  # initialize sum
i = 1  # initialize counter
while i <= n:
    sum = sum + i
    i = i+1  # update counter
print("The sum is", sum)
```

Comment: Adding together the numbers 1-4 gives 10. If `sum` was initialised to 1, the code would print 11 (because 1+1+2+3+4 = 11). However, is is possible to refactor the code so that it would give the correct result.

Comment: What do you mean in *why sum is initialized to 0, not 1*? well, you initialize it with 0, yourself, on line 2 - `sum = 0  # initialize sum`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually more of a basics in computer programming than Python question. I'll try to explain in brief here.

Looks like your goal is to find the sum of integers 1 to n.
If you initialize the `sum` with 1, then the result you get will be always 1 more than the actual sum of integers 1 to n. You can verify that by doing runs with small values of `n`, say up to 5 and comparing the output you get with the actual sum. I'll put a table here for convenience:

```
n | sum(1, n)
-------------
1 |         1
2 |         3
3 |         6
4 |        10
5 |        15
```

Now compare this to the output when `sum` is initialized with 1. For curiosity's sake, you can play with initializing with other values too.

Answer (score 0):

Sum is initialized to zero, but because the less than or equal to of n and i you always run at least one loop, take i = 1, then the sum is still one because the loop checks if 1 is less than or equal to 1 (i <= n). since it is then it adds i to the sum (ie. 1) making sum 1. it then updates i to 2 and goes to the top of the while loop. Since 2 <= 1 or i <= n is false here it breaks out and prints one as the sum